# Powershell escape character nested quantifier

Tags: powershell, escaping

Im having a tough time with the escape characters and using the "+" character.

I keep getting error regarding nested quantifier, "+"

```
$software= "Notepad++ 7.8.5 (x64)"
if($software-contains "++")
{
$software.Replace("++","\`'+""\`+'") 
}

Get-Content "C:\path\software.log" | Select-String $software
```

How can I get this error to subside?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a string *verbatim*, you can bypass the need to escape with [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)'s `-SimpleMatch` switch:

```
Get-Content C:\path\software.log | Select-String $software -SimpleMatch
```

If you do need *regex* matching, use [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape) to escape (potentially a *part* of) your pattern in order to have the regex engine treat it verbatim:

```
Get-Content C:\path\software.log | Select-String ([regex]::Escape($software))
```